# Using ldapModify to delete objectClass in LDAP entry

Tags: ldap

I have a need to delete three different objectClasses from a bunch of LDAP entries. Here's my ldif file:

```
dn: uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=net
changetype: modify
delete: objectClass
objectClass: top
-
delete: objectClass
objectClass: organizationalPerson
-
delete: objectClass
objectClass: person
```

When I run the ldapmodify command, I get the following output:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://server.net )
delete objectClass:
        top
delete objectClass:
        organizationalPerson
delete objectClass:
        person
modifying entry "uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=net"
modify complete
```

However, when I perform an ldapsearch on that user, all the objectClasses are still there. Clearly, it matches the object class name otherwise it would complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your entries have attributes that require the objectClasses your are trying to remove.  You need to remove the attributes that depend on the objectClasses before you remove the object class.

I don't know which LDAP server you are using, but I have had to remove entries to remove object clasees.  This was done by extracting the record, removing the original record, and adding the record with a modified list of object classes.  The add fails if you keep attributes not supported by the new object class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the objectClasses or the directory entry?

I kind of get the idea you want to remove the entire entry (i.e. record for the person).
If so the tool to use is  `ldapdelete` and it is generally installed at the same time as `ldapmodify` ?

Depending on which suite of tools it comes from (e.g. proprietary, OpenLDAP etc) it's generally pretty much the same syntax ad you just feed it DNs.

e.g. `ldapdelete -x -D uid=admin -w secret -H ldap://ldapserver.blah uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=net`

If it really is the objectClasses you want to use then you can turn up verbosity (-v with opneldap tools) or debugging  (-d   with openldap tools) to get a better idea of your problem.

As Bill Thor suggests you're probably having schema issues and you may well have to take a backup of the entries as they are and then re-add them as you want them to be if schema checking is enforced.

Or turn off schema checking temporarily do your thing and turn on schema checking again.